# malloc assertion failed when trying to write into a file

Tags: c

Context : I'm making a Huffman compression script in C. Even though it isn't efficient, I have to write the header onto the compressed file so I can decompress the file later on.

This is what a header looks like ( in plain-text ) :

```
e=01010;
```

This is the function that writes the header for each character in my huffman tree :

```
void write_header(struct node_m *node, FILE *stream)
{
  unsigned char buffer[get_len(node) + 3];
  buffer[0] = get_value(node);
  buffer[1] = '=';

  int i = 2;
  unsigned char *coding = get_coding(node);

  while (coding[i - 2])
  {
    buffer[i] = coding[i - 2];
    i++;
  }
  buffer[i] = ';';
  fwrite(buffer, sizeof(unsigned char), i + 1, stream);
}
```

A `struct node_m` contains these two fields that are essential to my function : `value` which is a `unsigned char` that contains the caracter the node represents, and `coding` which is a string of `unsigned char` that represents the encoding in this format : `01010`.

Running the function with GDB :

```
331   fwrite(buffer, sizeof(unsigned char), i + 1, stream);
(gdb) p buffer
$1 = "h=00000;"
(gdb) p sizeof(unsigned char)
$2 = 1
(gdb) p i+1
$3 = 8
(gdb) p stream
$4 = (FILE *) 0x0
(gdb) p get_len(node)
$5 = 5
(gdb) n

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__GI__IO_fwrite (buf=0x7fffffffce30, size=1, count=8, fp=0x0) at iofwrite.c:37
37  iofwrite.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) n

Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
The program no longer exists.
```

On my terminal, when running the whole thing, it doesn't tell me I got a segmentation fault, but rather this :

```
compresse: malloc.c:2394: sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == initial_top (av) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= MINSIZE && prev_inuse (old_top) && ((unsigned long) old_end & (pagesize - 1)) == 0)' failed.
Makefile:73: recipe for target 'compresse' failed
make: *** [compresse] Aborted (core dumped)
```

`compresse` is my main file that contains the `main()`.

I'm quite lost as to what I've done wrong here.

Comment: Go back a few steps, and look at what the `stream` pointer is. Then go back a few steps more to where you open the file. Have you checked that the `fopen` call was successful (i.e. didn't return a null pointer)?

Comment: When `get_len(node)` returns 0, `buffer[i] = ';';` is a buffer overrun.

Comment: Are you sure that coding[i - 2] is always defined? Assume that coding is all 1s, then the loop will run until it overflows in both buffer and coding

Comment: As you can see you have a few chances of [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) (and there are probably others that we don't know about). And as soon as you have undefined behavior, any speculation about behavior is useless.

Comment: `get_len(node)` won't return 0. I call this function into a leaf and I've already done multiple testing on my huffman tree. @mnistic

Comment: @JakubJudas yes. i have made sure coding always ends with `'\0'`

Comment: @truvaking Wait; The stream from your gdb does not look right - So I agree with some programmer dude - try to check where the file was open without errors and if the handle was properly passed to write_header

Comment: ok, i'm gonna check

Comment: sorry, i misstyped my gdb command, editing my main pot